# Could this be a sign of firmware infection?

Tags: firmware

I am burning an iso onto a CD using CD burning software. Before burning I take the 512sum of the image. After burning, I extract the image off the CD and check the sum again to make sure, and I get an incorrect checksum.

Thinking there was a glitch in the process, I do the entire process over again with the exact same results.

Then I boot a different OS and do the exact same things. Each time I copy the image from the burned CD, I get an incorrect check sum but the same incorrect checksum everytime. Is the iso possibly being modified while burning?

All this is being done on live distros on a computer with no harddisk or network interfaces. The CD is read using an external DVD drive and I am reasonably sure that the Live OSs and isos are clean.

It is weird that I keep getting the same incorrect checksum everytime I write back the image.
Is this a sign of a persistent infection?

If this is an infection and the problem is the DVD drive, how can I check this without possibly infecting another computer?

Comment: How do you get the checksum of the burnt disc?

Comment: `dd`d to a file then get the checksum of that.

Comment: Have you checked whether the sizes match? I wouln’t be surprised if they did not.

Comment: Please see, maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145611/why-does-my-burned-ubuntu-dvd-have-a-different-hash-checksum-than-the-iso

Comment: @user2233709: It is not, but is close to it. I have burned many other CDs before and this has never happened with any of them. Is there a reason why the size of the image burned is larger than the original image in this case?

Comment: @user942937 look at the end to see if it was padded with zeroes, and if that explains the whole difference. https://askubuntu.com/a/177625

Comment: If it does not, try the `dd` command listed there and use the `diff` command to see what changed, and where.

Comment: @Refineo: I tried using the slowest speed like is says in the answer, but I get the same result.

Comment: @J.A.K.: according to cmp it checks out. How can I tell if it's been padded only with zeroes?

Comment: `hexdump file.iso | tail -n 1000` might do it, just guessing. `-n 1000` would depend on how much they differ in size.

Comment: @J.A.K.: I tried reading the contents of the images using `cat | tail` and got an exact match. Using `hexdump | tail ` on both gave me the exact same results except for the [last line](https://i.imgsafe.org/4a/4a7f1945e8.png).